# c# wpf | create complex object with user-defined name to Serialize into JSON

Tags: c#, json, wpf, object, json.net

I'm making a basic WPF c# chat app and would like to allow users to register an account. the program would append a JSON file with a structure like:

```
{
    "user1":{
                "password":"password1"
            },
    "user2":{
                "password":"password2"
            }
}
```

replacing user1 & 2 with their username and password1 & 2 with their password.

iv'e tried using brackets;

```
//user is the name of the TextBox that the user puts their username into
//pass is the name of the password box ^

Object [user.Text] = new
{
    password = new {
        pass.Password
    }
};
```

but that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this would to deserialize the existing data, add the newly registered user. Serialize it back again. 
For example, with the current example given, if you need to a user.

```
var currentUserCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>(str);
currentUserCollection.Add("user3",new Dictionary<string,string>{["password"]="password3"});
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentUserCollection);
```

That would produce an output as

```
{
    "user1": {
        "password": "password1"
    },
    "user2": {
        "password": "password2"
    },
    "user3": {
        "password": "password3"
    }
}
```

Comment: @RRKS101_1TF2 Glad to help you. It would be great if you could mark it as Answer so that it would help any one looking for similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to have your users as different entries. Your use case is holding the set of all users in a JSON file? If so, you could change your json object structure to an easier one.
For example:

```
public class UserSet {
    public List<User> Users {get; set;}
}

public class User{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And then, when you add a new user, you just create a new object with his username and password, and then add it to the list of all users.

Comment: My reasoning is that I have a dispatch timer checking the username and password every 5ms, so searching may be a bit too slow.